# Can't create an event using google calendar api php

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I've followed  all the instructions, the php quickstart and the events.insert pages by google; but when i run it the consent form pops up I click allow and then nothing happens bar the consent form resetting.If i change the redirect url to another page then it no longer resets the consent form, but still nothing happens.

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAuthConfig('redacted');

$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");

$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events");

$client->setRedirectUri('http://redacted/GoogleClientWorksCalendar.php');//this is the current file

$client->setAccessType('offline');

$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

$client->setPrompt('consent');

$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'test',
  'location' => 'somewhere',
  'description' => 'test description',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2020-09-03T09:00:00+02:00',

  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2020-09-03T17:00:00+02:00',

  ),



));

$calendarId = 'redacted';
$results = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```

Thank you.

Comment: I should point out that the consent form re running means there is an issue with the subsequent creation of an event code, because i already have used other google apis and whenever the consent form re ran it meant that there was an issue with the following code.

Comment: have you tried printing the results?  The consent form will rerun because your not storing the credentials.

Comment: Thing is, I've been able to get other google apis to work with the same structure, and whenever the consent form re ran it meant that the subsequent request (in this case to create an event) is wrong. Would you know why?

Comment: Cant tell without seeing the debuging code.  Your getting an error you just not catching it or checking for it.

Comment: Honestly I'm a php rookie, so I have no idea what that means. All I know is there's an error in the request to create an event, because I had a similar issue when using the google drive api.

Comment: Put a try catch around the call so that you can see the error

Comment: Sorry to ask this... but how do you do that?

Comment: Also is the call to create a new event correct or am I using an outdated api version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. The problem was I had forgotten a part of the google Oauth2.0 code required, which meant I never received the  access token.
This snippet below is fully functional. Hope it helps and thank you all for answering.

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAuthConfig('redacted');

$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");

$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events");

$client->setRedirectUri('http://redacted/GoogleClientWorksCalendar.php');//this is the current file

$client->setAccessType('offline');

$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

$client->setPrompt('consent');

$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'test',
  'location' => 'somewhere',
  'description' => 'test description',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2020-09-03T09:00:00+02:00',

  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2020-09-03T17:00:00+02:00',

  ),



));

$calendarId = 'redacted';
$results = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```